# Data Driven Test Case for Login page

Tags: python, selenium

The login page shows a' WELCOME :)' message after successful login and 'ACCESS DENIED!' after failed. The target page is the same(means driver.title is the same). I tried the below code:

```
    if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[contains (text(),'WELCOME :)')]"):
       print("Testcase Pass")
       XLUtils.writeData(path, 'Sheet1', r, 3, "Pass")        
    else: 
       #driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h3[contains (text(),'ACCESS DENIED!')]")
       print("Testcase Failed")
       XLUtils.writeData(path, 'Sheet1', r, 3, "Failed")
    driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "GO BACK").click()
```

During login failed, 'else:' statement won't work and gives below exception.
*selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//h3[contains (text(),'WELCOME :)')]"}
(Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)*

It's my beginner stage :)
Is there a way to do this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `try/except`  - see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) for more information

```
try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[contains (text(),'WELCOME :)')]")
    print("Testcase Pass")
    XLUtils.writeData(path, 'Sheet1', r, 3, "Pass")        
except:
    print("Testcase Failed")
    XLUtils.writeData(path, 'Sheet1', r, 3, "Failed")
```

This is a general catch all. Any error in the try steps will log a fail.

It might be worth a refactor to ensure that only the find_element can result in a failed step (and not the excel):

```
try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[contains (text(),'WELCOME :)')]")
    print("Testcase Pass")
    result = "Testcase Pass"    
except:
    print("Testcase Failed")
    result = "Testcase Failed"    

XLUtils.writeData(path, 'Sheet1', r, 3, result)
```

---

If you need it, it's also possible to limit the scope of the `except` by importing the error:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
try:
    # Pass conde
except NoSuchElementException:
    # no such element catch code
```

This can be useful if you want more control and want to handle different exceptions in different ways.